# javascript array assignment: arr vs. [...arr]

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference, variable-assignment

Consider:

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3];
let myArray2 = myArray;
let myArray3 = [...myArray];
```

What is the difference between the assignments for `myArray2` and `myArray3`?  Is myArray2 a reference to the same memory as myArray (so if `myArray.shift()`, the value of `myArray2` also changes), whereas `myArray3` is a copy of `myArray`?

Clarification:  I understand `[...myArray]` creates a copy of the array.  I'm not clear if `myArray2 = myArray` also creates a copy, or creates a a second reference to the same array, so changing the array via one will be reflected when getting the value via the other.

Comment: `let myArray = [1, 2, 3];
let myArray2 = myArray;
let myArray3 = [...myArray];
myArray[2] = "HI";
console.log("myArray2", myArray2)
console.log("myArray3", myArray3)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092646/i-want-mean-in-javascript-three-point-operator

Comment: don't think that this is the same question as the one that is marked as duplicate of

Comment: @Quentin, this is not a duplicate. This is more about spread operator and deep copy : 
`let myArray = [1, 2, [0,0],{a:1}];
let myArray2 = myArray;
let myArray3 = [...myArray];

myArray[2]=[1,1];
myArray[3].a=5;
myArray[4]=6;

console.log(myArray,myArray2,myArray3);`

Comment: "*I'm not clear if `myArray2 = myArray` also creates a copy, or creates a a second reference to the same array, so changing the array via one will be reflected when getting the value via the other*" - Then write some code and *test* it. Can easily be done in a web browser console in the about same amount of time it took you to edit your answer!

Comment: Thanks to all for the comments. I now have an answer. I believe this to be a different question than the ones referenced, but I cannot add an answer because this question has been closed.  So, for easy reference, here's what I found helpful:
let myArray = [1, 2, [0,0],{a:1}];
let myArray2 = myArray;
let myArray3 = [...myArray];
myArray[2][0]=99;
myArray[2]=[1,1];
myArray[2][0]=22;
myArray[3].a=5;
myArray[4]=6;
console.log(myArray);
console.log(myArray2);
console.log(myArray3);
yields:
[1, 2, [22, 1], Object {a=5}, 6]
[1, 2, [22, 1], Object {a=5}, 6]
[1, 2, [99, 0], Object {a=5}]